# Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, jestjs, es6-promise

I am trying to test a method using Jest... The method should return Promise.reject() .

Here is the code I wrote:

```
test('testing Invalid Response Type', () => {       
        const client = new DataClient();

        client.getSomeData().then(response => {
            console.log("We got data: "+ response);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log("in catch");
            expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(IncorrectResponseTypeError);

        });
        expect.assertions(1);

  });
```

When I run the test, it prints "in catch" but fails with this exception:
 **Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.**

```
console.log src/data/dataclient.test.js:25
      in catch

  ● testing Invalid Response Type

    expect.assertions(1)

    Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.

      at extractExpectedAssertionsErrors (node_modules/expect/build/extract_expected_assertions_errors.js:37:19)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: Looks like you are not having a matching errorType. (You caught an error, but it was not of the type `IncorrectResponseTypeError`)

Comment: Maybe you can try logging `e` in your console to see what type it actually is

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by adding return statement before the block.
With return statement the function will wait for catch block to finish.. and hence expect will be executed..

```
test('testing Invalid Response Type', () => {       
    const client = new DataClient();
    return client.getSomeData().then(response => {
            console.log("We got data: "+ response);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log("in catch");
            expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(IncorrectResponseTypeError);

        });
        expect.assertions(1);
   });
```

Comment: what if you're using async/await?

Comment: You are returning before `expect.assertions(1);` is run.

Comment: @ckim16 see my answer, no reason not to

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the promise to finish to check number of assertions (to reach the `.catch` block).

see [jest's asynchronous tutorial](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#asyncawait), specially the async/await solution. Actually, their example is almost identical to your problem.

in your example, you would do:

```
test('testing Invalid Response Type', async () => { // <-- making your test async!      
    const client = new DataClient();

    await client.getSomeData().then(response => { // <-- await for your function to finish
        console.log("We got data: "+ response);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log("in catch");
        expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(IncorrectResponseTypeError);

    });
    expect.assertions(1);

});
```

Btw, the accepted solution also works, but not suitable to multiple tests of async code