# Why does Jest say there are assertion calls when no exception is thrown?

Tags: jestjs

While adding `expect.hasAssertions()` and `expect.assertions(0)` to my existing Jest (js) tests, I found Jest was unexpectedly failing *some* tests due to a mismatch between the expected and actual number of assertion calls.

> Expected zero assertions to be called but received one assertion call.

I found that even if I created a project from scratch and add incredibly simple tests, Jest would fail due to the expected/actual assertion calls.

Eg.
Adding `expect.assertions(0)` to example from Jest's website fails

```
test('two plus two is four', () => {
        // I'd think this would pass but it fails
        expect.assertions(0);
        expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
});
```

Adding `expect.hasAssertions()` to example from Jest's website passes

```
test('two plus two is four', () => {
        // I'd think this would fail but it passes
        expect.hasAssertions();
        expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
});
```

Why is Jest saying there are assertion calls when no exception is thrown?

Jest: 26.4.2,
Node: 13.11.0,
NPM: 6.13.7

*Note: this is not the same as [Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248905/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect.assertions` asserts that there is a specified number of *assertions*, i.e. `expect(...)...` calls. `expect.assertions` asserts that there are assertions. They don't assert that there are specifically *failed assertions*. They will take failed assertions into account too, but since a test fails on first failed assertion, counting them doesn't make sense.

Since there is 1 assertion (`expect(2 + 2).toBe(4)`), `expect.assertions(0)` fails.

For this reason these ones will pass:

```
test('two plus two is four', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
});

test('two plus two is four', () => {
    expect.hasAssertions();
    expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
});
```

These ones will fail:

```
test('two plus two is four', () => {
    expect.assertions(0);
    expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
});

test('two plus two is four', () => {
    expect.hasAssertions();
});
```

Comment: For some reason I was treating it as specifically the number of errors thrown. It's all making sense now. Thanks for your polite response to a dumb moment.